# General direction of Lua Macro

Tags: lua

Ok so I will say, I am not an expert on Lua.
I am just trying to make a simple macro in Logitech G Hub. I want it to change my mouse location when I fire in a game. Basically recoil adjustment as a project.

```
function onEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
        OutputLogMessage("Script ON")
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(-1, 13)
                        Sleep(75)
                        OutputLogMessage("mouse clicked")
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end
```

^^^Code here. I when I run it in repel it nothing happens as expected but when I run it in Logitech g hub still nothing hap9pens. Is there something I am doing wrong here ? Any guidance appreciated. If you simply want to guide me in a direction that is ok too. Thanks for anyone's time spent :-)

NEW STUFF-------------------------------------------------------------

Ok after some suggestions I am posting the most recent version of code here. Its Very simplified. I am still having an issue where it is not doing it. However I get my console readout after the application it is meant for closes. This is confusing. Also it is just the console readout so idk. Going to read through the Lua pdf document thing and see if theres anything in there I am doing wrong. Updated code below. Anyone can try and lettme know if they are having same issue.

[image]

Comment: Try to insert `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)` before your code

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I tried that, also I tried changing the one part from mouse 3 too 2 and I still am unable to get the log output to write "fired". Any Shuggestions?

Comment: Insert `Sleep(10)` before `if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I mean some progress. idk, check the updated version of my code I left. Try for urself if u want. for me it fires the event (console readout at least) after I close the application.

Comment: Your code works, because it prints "mouse clicked" from the loop.  The only problem is the argument `-1000` is beyond the valid range `-127...+127`, so the mouse might behave unpredictably.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ah, thanks I think I missed that part in the Lua pdf. Also I think something is wrong with the software as well so I will restart that. Will answer this question if I get it to work!